# Skew-symmetric matrix and exp function $e^A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

Let $A_{nXn}(\mathbb{R})$ Skew-symmetric matrix $A=-A^t$ prove that $e^A(e^A)^t=I$

while:
$e^A=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n}{n!}$

I tried this:
$A=-A^t \Rightarrow A$ is Diagonalizable with orthogonal basis over
  $\mathbb{C}$ $\Rightarrow A=PDP^*$and $P^*=P^{-1}$ 
and D is:
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1 &0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n
 \end{pmatrix}
we know that :$\lambda_i=0$ or $\lambda_i=ib$ for $b \in R$  because A is Skew-symmetric matrix.
so: $e^A=Pe^DP^t$
so if I will prove that $\lambda_i=0$ we will get $e^A=PP^t=I$. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can see *easily* that the linear map

$$\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)\rightarrow \mathcal M_n(\Bbb R),\quad A\mapsto A^t$$ 
is continuous hence we have

$$\left(e^A\right)^t=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{A^k}{k!}\right)^t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{A^k}{k!}\right)^t=e^{A^t}=e^{-A}$$
and the result follows from the fact: if $AB=BA$ then
$$e^Ae^B=e^{A+B}$$

Comment: actually it's looks amazing but we didn't learn that this map is continuous(doesn't part of the course). so I think that I need to prove it with more "algebraic" way. Do you have other suggestion ? what about the way I mentioned in the Question? tnx!

Comment: I didn't see an alternative answer. For the way you mentioned notice that the diagonalization of the skew-symmetric matrix is more complicated than you wrote. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory).

Comment: fixed it, now it is over C